# Couldn't use data file .coverage: unable to open database file

Tags: python, dockerfile, code-coverage, alpine-linux

A strange issue with permissions occured when pushing to GitHub. I have a test job which runs tests with coverage and then pushes results to codecov on every push and pull request. However, this scenario only works with root user.

If running with `digitalshop` user it throws an error:

```
Couldn't use data file '/digital-shop-app/.coverage': unable to open database file
```

My question is: how to run coverage in docker container so it won't throw this error? My guess is that it's because of permissions.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  test:
    build: .
    command: >
      sh -c "
        python manage.py wait_for_db &&
        coverage run --source='.' manage.py test mainapp.tests &&
        coverage report &&
        coverage xml
      "
    volumes: 
      - ./digital-shop-app:/digital-shop-app
    env_file: .env
    depends_on: 
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
COPY ./digital-shop-app /digital-shop-app
COPY ./scripts /scripts

WORKDIR /digital-shop-app

RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    apk add --no-cache bash && \
    apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client && \
    apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-deps \
        build-base jpeg-dev postgresql-dev musl-dev linux-headers \
        zlib-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev python3-dev cargo && \
    apk add --update --no-cache libjpeg && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /requirements.txt && \
    apk del .tmp-deps && \
    adduser --disabled-password --no-create-home digitalshop && \
    chown -R digitalshop:digitalshop /py/lib/python3.9/site-packages && \
    chmod -R +x /scripts

ENV PATH="/scripts:/py/bin:/py/lib:$PATH"

USER digitalshop

CMD ["run.sh"]
```

Comment: Small round of tips: make your issue as small and focused as possible: can you reproduce this without the complexity of GitHub action, in a simple run of docker compose on your machine? Then, next step: what is the smaller python code to reproduce it. Then you will have a [mre] that, hopefully, someone can help you with.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Thanks for useful tips. You gave me food for thought. As you mentioned, I tried without GitHub Actions on a local machine and found the problem. Coverage didn't create `.coverage` file because my user didn't own the directory. Also I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up creating another Dockerfile called `Dockerfile.test` and putting pretty much the same configuration except non-admin user creation. Here's the final variant:

**Running code as root user is not recommended thus please read UPDATE section**

Dockerfile.test:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
COPY ./digital-shop-app /digital-shop-app

WORKDIR /digital-shop-app

RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    apk add --no-cache bash curl gnupg coreutils && \
    apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client libjpeg && \
    apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-deps \
        build-base jpeg-dev postgresql-dev musl-dev linux-headers \
        zlib-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev python3-dev cargo && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /requirements.txt && \
    apk del .tmp-deps

ENV PATH="/py/bin:/py/lib:$PATH"
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  test:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.test
    command: >
      sh -c "
        python manage.py wait_for_db &&
        coverage run --source='.' manage.py test mainapp.tests &&
        coverage report &&
        coverage xml
      "
    volumes: 
      - ./digital-shop-app:/digital-shop-app
    env_file: .env
    depends_on: 
      - db
```

I don't know exactly whether it is a good practice. If not then please tell how to do it correctly.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to [@β.εηοιτ.βε](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2123530/%ce%b2-%ce%b5%ce%b7%ce%bf%ce%b9%cf%84-%ce%b2%ce%b5) for giving me food for thought.

After some local debugging I found out that coverage needs user to own the directory where `.coverage` file is located. So I created subdir named `/cov` inside project folder and set `digitalshop` user as its owner including everything inside. Finally I specified path to `.coverage` file by setting env variable `COVERAGE_FILE=/digital-shop-app/cov/.coverage` where `digital-shop-app` is project root folder. And also specified the same path to `coverage.xml` report in `docker-compose.yml`. Here's the code:

docker-compose.yml (added `-o` flag to `coverage xml` command):

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  test:
    build:
      context: .
    command: >
      sh -c "
        python manage.py wait_for_db &&
        coverage run --source='.' manage.py test mainapp.tests &&
        coverage xml -o /digital-shop-app/cov/coverage.xml
      "
    env_file: .env
    depends_on: 
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
COPY ./digital-shop-app /digital-shop-app
COPY ./scripts /scripts

WORKDIR /digital-shop-app

RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    apk add --no-cache bash && \
    apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client && \
    apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-deps \
        build-base jpeg-dev postgresql-dev musl-dev linux-headers \
        zlib-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev python3-dev cargo && \
    apk add --update --no-cache libjpeg && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /requirements.txt && \
    apk del .tmp-deps && \
    adduser --disabled-password --no-create-home digitalshop && \
    chown -R digitalshop:digitalshop /py/lib/python3.9/site-packages && \
    chmod -R +x /scripts && \
    # New code here
    mkdir -p /digital-shop-app/cov && \
    chown -R digitalshop:digitalshop /digital-shop-app/cov

ENV PATH="/scripts:/py/bin:/py/lib:$PATH"

USER digitalshop

CMD ["run.sh"]
```

Comment: No, you shouldn't run a container with root, indeed. but you are lacking a [mre] so we can reproduce and help you.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

I ran into the same error when running pytest with coverage using docker-compose in the github-hosted `ubuntu-latest` image in GitHub Actions. This is an instance of the [Docker host file system owner matching problem](https://www.fullstaq.com/knowledge-hub/blogs/docker-and-the-host-filesystem-owner-matching-problem).

In short, the [user on the host (the github action runner)](https://github.com/myoung34/docker-github-actions-runner/wiki/Usage#non-root-runners) and the user in on the container (where my pytest suite runs) have different UIDs. The mounted directory `app` is owned by the user on the host. When the user in the container attempts to write to the `app/.coverage`, permission is denied (since this user is not the owner).

## The fix

In my case, I solved the issue by matching the UID of my docker image's default user with that of the github actions runner user, `1001`. I added this to my `Dockerfile` to accomplish this:

```
# Make the default user have the same UID as the github actions "runner" user.
# This to avoid permission issues when mounting volumes.
USER root
RUN usermod --uid 1001 <image_default_user>
USER <image_default_user>
```

## All relevant files

`app/test_utils/docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./test_utils/Dockerfile
    container_name: app
    volumes:
      - ..:/app
```

`app/test_utils/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM <my base image>

# Make the default user have the same UID as the github actions "runner" user.
# This to avoid permission issues when mounting volumes, see
USER root
RUN usermod --uid 1001 <image_default_user>
USER <image_default_user>

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt -r requirements_test.txt
```

`app/.github/unittests.yml`:

```yaml
name: Run unit tests, Report coverage

on:
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - app/*
      - .github/workflows/unittests.yml

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checks out the repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Build docker image
        run: docker-compose -f test_utils/docker-compose.yml build

      - name: Run unit tests & produce coverage report
        # Adapted from the docker example in
        # https://github.com/MishaKav/pytest-coverage-comment?tab=readme-ov-file#example-usage
        run: |
          docker-compose \
            -f test_utils/docker-compose.yml \
            run app \
            pytest \
              --cov-report=term-missing:skip-covered \
              --junitxml=/app/pytest.xml \
              --cov=/app \
              /app \
            | tee pytest-coverage.txt

      - name: Pytest coverage comment
        uses: MishaKav/pytest-coverage-comment@main
        with:
          pytest-coverage-path: pytest-coverage.txt
          junitxml-path: pytest.xml
```